# How to correctly set the camera

Tags: three.js

I am having trouble knowing how the set the camera. What i have tried is using a example and just changing the OBJLoader url to my file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - OBJLoader + MTLLoader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - OBJLoader + MTLLoader
        </div>

        <script src="../build/three.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/DDSLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container, stats;
            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            init();
            render();

            function init() {
                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
                camera.position.z = -25;

                // scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                //directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

                var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.load( '140018_2.mtl', function( materials ) {
                    materials.preload();

                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                    objLoader.load( '140018_2.obj', function ( object ) {

                        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
                        console.log("loaded");

                        scene.add( object );
                    });
                });

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // add this only if there is no animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
                controls.enableZoom = true;
            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }

            function render() {
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It somewhat works. When i load the page i dont see anything. But when i zoom out, the object 'flies in' from the top left corner of my screen. All i really need is just for the object to be centered on the screen.

How are you guys achieving this? The OBJ is not created by me and its settings (height, width etc etc) can vary.

Comment: So it seems this has to do with lighting...

Comment: Maybe your camera is not far enough away from the center `camera.position.z = -25`. The fact that you say "the object 'flies in' from the top left corner" suggests to me that your .OBJ is not centred, as in, when it was exported from the 3D editor, it was not centred .

Comment: That could be very well possible. Is it possible to center it with ThreeJS?

Comment: you may be able to by way of the objects bounding box, but without seeing the .OBJ, I could not be certain. When exporting to .OBJ, a stay vertex can result in an export not being centred.

Comment: Would you have a moment to look at the OBJ? Or maybe give me some pointers to see myself if its centered

Comment: Sure, make the obj available to me somewhere

Comment: @2pa : https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/200d40a6d664c250a52897c462cc557c20160712101410/ab64f29107c02ff00f0f2f70264a05d220160712101410/b2bb90

Comment: Try this one, I just centered the model and rotated it so it was the right way up. If this one does allow you to see the model when your scene is loaded then you know it is because the model is not centered properly. https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/81b58eeeedd208e8a1e704351647ae2920160712103453/437e1c39e5000904d2af7500c8e8183120160712103453/cde678

Comment: Yes, that shows it as expected. So still some work to do! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you say "the object 'flies in' from the top left corner" suggests to me that your .OBJ is not centred, as in, when it was exported from the 3D editor, it was not centred.
It will need to be centred in the 3D authoring program and exported again.